# Azure Data Factory: how to specify "drop-by" extents when sink is a Kusto table?

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-data-explorer

I'm using Azure Data Factory to move data from a SQL DB into Kusto (Azure Data Explorer).
The last activity (sink) in my flow is configured like this:

[image: ADF Kusto Sink]

The transformation and ingestion works fine but I'd like to be able to set a tag for my imported data, so that I can drop the extent if needed, as shown in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/extents-overview#drop-by-extent-tags):

```
.ingest ... with @'{"tags":"[\"drop-by:2016-02-17\"]"}'
.drop extents <| .show table MyTable extents where tags has "drop-by:2016-02-17"
```

How/where can I provide the tag when using ADF?

Comment: Seems possible for copy activity, using additionalProperties. Couldn't find any relevant for Dataflow

Comment: It does solve the problem, doesn't it? I can use a copy activity to work around the original problem.

Comment: In a cumbersome way where there is clearly a neater one, while stating wrong claims.   UtkarshPal-MT didn't bother to actually open an ADF and try it / read the ADF documentation.

Comment: Possibly. But your comment clarified this. And to be honest: whether the goal can be achieved by editing a JSON file or by using a UI, isn't that secondary?

Comment: You could give a chance (and some motivation) to @UtkarshPal-MT to fix is answer and perhaps even verify that it actually works as expected, so it will have a greater value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, dataflow doesn't allow to add tags to the datasets in Azure Data Explorer.

But as a workaround, you can store the dataset after transformation in sink location and then use `Copy activity` to copy the data to another or same Data Explorer as copy activity allows `AdditionalProperties`  when copying to Azure Data Explorer.

**Note:** This feature is currently available by manually editing the JSON payload.

Add a single row under the "sink" section of the copy activity as follows:

```
"sink": {
    "type": "AzureDataExplorerSink",
    "additionalProperties": "{\"tags\":\"[\\\"drop-by:account_FiscalYearID_2020\\\"]\"}"
},
```

Refer: [Specify AdditionalProperties when copying to Azure Data Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/data-factory-integration#specify-additionalproperties-when-copying-to-azure-data-explorer)

Comment: Why do you assume that you need to manually edit the JSON?

Comment: This is given in official document.

Comment: You might want to verify it and actually create an ADF sink. You might also want to take a look on the ADF documentation. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-data-explorer?tabs=data-factory#azure-data-explorer-as-sink

Answer (score 0):

You can now add the additional property with the 'Dynamic Content' option in the UI if you are using the ADF Copy Activity.

[Additonal Property script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JrsKP.png)

-> @json(concat('{"tags":"["drop-by:', item().Date, '"]"}'))

But this does not solve the fact that you cannot add Additional Properties to a ADF DataFlow Sink. Is there not another way of doing except for the above workaround?

Kind Regards